# What's the meaning behind S.A.D. and Smiles?

Tags: one-piece

From the Punk Hazard arc, we have learned that Vegapunk had created a unique substance called [S.A.D.](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SAD), which is one of the few things needed to create [Smiles](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Artificial_Devil_Fruit#Smiles), artificial Zoan Devil Fruits.

So basically we have (a joker) using sadness to create smiles. I doubt Oda named both objects that way accidentally. So does anybody know if Oda has ever mentioned what the symbolism is behind S.A.D and Smiles?

Comment: I think it might be too early to know the answer for this. The insinuations I see is that the one produced before Luffy got to the new world are going to be more relevant when they are in use later in the story.

Answer (score 2):

The substance is just "SAD" not "S.A.D". Considering that Caesar Clown is the only person in the world who knows how to manufacture it, and he uses it to create artificial fruits that he calls "smiles", it was just an appropriate name to fit into the theme. Clown, smiles, sad, etc.

[image: SAD vat]

Answer (score 0):

**SAD and SMILES are named after the side effects of Artificial devil fruits**

A normal devil fruit grants power and has only a side effect of unable to swim, but artificial devil fruits are different on top of unable to swim

> they also lose the ability to become SAD or angry, they can only SMILE or laugh

---

> [image: Meaning behind SAD and SMILE 1]
>  [image: Meaning behind SAD and SMILE 2]

Source: Chapter 943: SMILE